403 forbidden error while fetching file from aws transcribe service
I am trying to fetch file created after transcription service on printing the uri for the job I am able to get the uri:
---------------transcription successfull--------------- https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/abcd/transcribe_1234561119.json
but using the requests to fetch the file:
response=requests.get(response)
print(response)

my output:bound method Response.json of <Response [403]>>
